# Why is Cython Decorator version slower than Cython Pyx version?

Tags: python, cython

I am trying all sorts of ways to write the factorial function in Cython. First I tried the pyx file version in iPython Notebook.

```
%%file pyxfact.pyx
cdef long pyxfact(long n):
    if n <=0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * pyxfact(n-1)

def fact(long n):
    return pyxfact(n)
```

Then I tried the same, as least I think so, in Cython decorator, like this:

```
%%file cydecofact.py
import cython

@cython.cfunc # equivalent to cdef, while @cython.ccall is equivalent to cpdef
@cython.returns(cython.long)
@cython.locals(n=cython.long)
def deco_fact(n):
    if n <=0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * deco_fact(n-1)

@cython.locals(n=cython.long)
def fact(n):
    return deco_fact(n)
```

To my surprise, the two versions have a huge run time difference:

```
%timeit -n 10000 pyxfact.fact(10)
%timeit -n 10000 cydecofact.fact(10)

10000 loops, best of 3: 219 ns per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 2 µs per loop
```

Comment: This might seem like a silly question, but did you compile the decorated version?

Comment: Creating a .py file with cython decorators does not automatically turn a python file into a cython file, it just allows the same file to be run without compilation. Also, within the ipython notebook, there is a %%cython magic which automates the compilation process.

Comment: @DaveP I get it that I must compile the pure python code with Cython decorator. I created a new %%cython cell and wrote `import cydecofact` and `deco_fact2 = cydecofact.deco_fact` in it. Then I tested deco_fact2 but it is still as slow.

Answer (score 2):

You need a `@cython.compile` to actually compile the code.  However, it looks like neither `cython.cfunc` nor recursion is supported for `@cython.compile`.